# Lightweight HTTP to HTTPS redirect

Tags: web-server, proxmox

We are running a Proxmox server, which I have configured using IPTables to redirect port 443 to the proxmox port 8006.  What would be the lightest way to redirect anyone trying to access http://proxmox.example.com to https://proxmox.example.com.  It feels like a shame to set up an entire web server on the system just to do an http redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimal:

```
while true ; do nc -l -p 80 \
  -c 'echo -e "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\nLocation: https://yourhost.example.com/\n\n"' ; done
```

although I'd run it via xinetd (and redirect to port 8006 rather than messing with iptables):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\nLocation: https://yourhost.example.com:8006/\n\n"
```

Comment: Nice trick with xinetd!

Comment: I believe its also possible to do the [x]inetd thing with systemd. I'm sure Google knows more.

Comment: Indeed. That quick search yields something along the lines of [systemd socket](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) to create a listener and a trivial service unit that responds to that socket; https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/end-road-systemds-socket-units/

Answer (score 2):

Since @symcbean mentioned using `systemd` sockets instead of `xinetd`, and I stumbled upon the same problem, I'll post my solution.

One needs to put two files in `/etc/systemd/system`.

This service, let's say we name it `http-to-https@.service` (note the trailing `@`), is executed each time a request is received by `systemd`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/echo -e "HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily\r\nLocation: https://proxmox.example.com/\r\n\r\n"
StandardInput=socket
```

This `socket` unit file tells `systemd` to `accept()` on port 80 and invokes `http-to-https@.service` to handle incoming connections. It needs to be named `http-to-https.socket`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

[Socket]
ListenStream=80
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Now just run

```
# systemctl enable http-to-https.socket
```

and `systemd` will do the job happily.

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a simple HTTP to HTTPS redirection without setting up a full web server for this purpose, you can achieve this using Nginx with minimal configuration. Here's how you can do it:

**Install Nginx:** you can install Nginx on your Proxmox server. You can use your package manager to do this. For example,
on a Debian-based system:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install nginx
```

**Create a Configuration File:** Create a simple Nginx configuration file for the redirection. You can create a new configuration file in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/ directory, for example, proxmox:

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/proxmox
```

Add the following configuration to the file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name proxmox.example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

This configuration listens on port 80 for requests to proxmox.example.com and issues a permanent (301) redirect to the equivalent HTTPS URL.

Then enable the Configuration and create a symbolic link to enable this configuration and then test the configuration:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/proxmox  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Then test your Nginx config that have no confilict

```
sudo nginx -t
```

If there was no conflict then just soft reload your Nginx.

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: While this might be overkill just for a redirect, using nginx to proxy the https trafic has a lot of benefits - notably load balancing/HA for proxmox cluster and applying additional authentication. But do read up on how to configure nginx specifically for Proxmox (the web sockets stuff needs additional tweaks on nginx).

Comment: Noted, thank you @symcbean